# CakePHP (sub)query to get youngest record of each group

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

In a project I manage invoices that have a status which is changed throughout their lifetime. The status changes are saved in another database table which is similar to this:

```
|id|invoice_id|user_id|old_status_id|new_status_id|change_date        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1|         1|      1|            1|            3|2013-11-11 12:00:00|
| 2|         1|      2|            3|            5|2013-11-11 12:30:00|
| 3|         2|      3|            1|            2|2013-11-10 08:00:00|
| 4|         1|      1|            5|            6|2013-11-11 13:10:00|
| 5|         2|      2|            2|            5|2013-11-10 09:00:00|
```

For each invoice, I would like to retrieve the last status change. Thus the result should contain the records with the ids 4 and 5.

```
|id|invoice_id|user_id|old_status_id|new_status_id|change_date        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4|         1|      1|            5|            6|2013-11-11 13:10:00|
| 5|         2|      2|            2|            5|2013-11-10 09:00:00|
```

If I group by the invoice_id and use max(change_date), I will retrieve the youngest date, but the field values of the other fields are not taken from those records containing the youngest date in the group.

That's challenge #1 for me.

Challenge #2 would be to realize the query with CakePHP's methods, if possible.

Challenge #3 would be to filter the result to those records belonging to the current user. SO if the current user has the id 1, the result is

```
|id|invoice_id|user_id|old_status_id|new_status_id|change_date        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4|         1|      1|            5|            6|2013-11-11 13:10:00|
```

If he or she has user id 2, the result is

```
|id|invoice_id|user_id|old_status_id|new_status_id|change_date        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5|         2|      2|            2|            5|2013-11-10 09:00:00|
```

For the user with id 3 the result would be empty.

In other words, I do **not** want to find **all** latest changes that a user has made, regardless whether he was the last one that made a change. Instead, I want to find all invoice changes where that user was the ast one so far who made a change. The motivation is that I want to enable a user to undo his change, which is only possible if no other user after him performed another change.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs an answer

Strictly focusing on:

**I want to find all invoice changes where that user was the last one so far who made a change**

Write the SQL as

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN foo AS after_foo
  ON foo.invoice_id = after_foo.invoice_id
    AND foo.change_date < after_foo.change_date
WHERE after_foo.id IS NULL
  AND foo.user_id = 1;
```

Implement using the `JOIN` clause within Cakephp's `find`.

---

The SQL for the suggested algorithm is something like:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
JOIN (SELECT invoice_id, MAX(change_date) AS most_recent
      FROM foo
      GROUP BY invoice_id) AS recently
  ON recently.invoice_id = foo.invoice_id
    AND recently.most_recent = foo.change_date
WHERE foo.user_id = 1;
```